# RayCaster stops detecting object when i call camera.lookAt()

Tags: 3d, three.js, raycasting

I am calling this whenever i click on the scene.

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
    controls.update();
    var position = new THREE.Vector3();
    position.setFromMatrixPosition( scene.group.children[0].matrixWorld );
    position.normalize();
    console.log(position);

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(); // create once
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(); // create once

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
    //console.log(mouse);

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    console.log(raycaster.ray.direction);

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.group.children , false );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
        console.log(intersects);
    }
}
```

initially when i have applied no rotation the click works, But as soon as i call

```
scope.target.x = offset * Math.sin( (scope.phi + iphi) * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos( (scope.theta + itheta) * Math.PI / 180 );
scope.target.y = offset * Math.cos( (scope.phi + iphi) * Math.PI / 180 );
scope.target.z = offset * Math.sin( (scope.phi + iphi) * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.sin( (scope.theta + itheta) * Math.PI / 180 );

scope.camera.lookAt( scope.target );
```

RayCaster do not return any object.

I have also noticed that my raycaster give same direction vector at same location of screen even after rotation.

Then i tried to apply rotation on raycaster manually

```
var e = new THREE.Euler(((controls.phi-90)/180)*Math.PI, 0, (controls.theta/180)*Math.PI, 'XYZ');
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
raycaster.ray.direction.applyEuler( e );
```

but now i get intersection at a nearby location by not at exact location of object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i was not updating world coordinates based on camera rotation calling

```
camera.updateMatrixWorld();
```

on camera update solved the problem.